# How to turn multi json to string seperated comma?

Tags: javascript

Is there shortcut method to convert people json object to string seperated comma without loop and temporary array variabel?

```
const person_names = [];

const people = [
  {
    'name': 'stephen'
  },
  {
    'name': 'tom'
  }
];

for (person of people)
{
  person_names.push(person.name);
}

console.log(person_names.join());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using .map()

```js
var people = [
  {
    'name': 'stephen'
  },
  {
    'name': 'tom'
  }
];


console.log(people.map(x => x.name ).join(","))
```